# RequireJS load same module twice to get two separate namespaces

Tags: javascript, node.js, requirejs

This example library, which uses RequireJS under a browser and uses amdefine instead under Node.js:

### lib.js

```
if (typeof define !== 'function') { var define = require('amdefine')(module); }
define([],function () {
    var opt = 0
    return {
        set: function(x) { opt = x },
        show: function() { console.log(opt) }
    }
})
```

Now here this library is used by the node sample program

### srv.js

```
var lib=require('./lib')
lib.set(111)
var lib2=require('./lib')
lib2.set(222)
lib.show()
lib2.show()
```

This is example program identical to above, but for a browser instead

### index.html

```
<script data-main="cli.js" src="require.js"></script>
```

### cli.js

```
requirejs(['lib','lib'], function(lib, lib2) {
    lib.set(111)
    lib2.set(222)
    lib.show()
    lib2.show()
});
```

both program will output:

### console log

```
222
222
```

but desired output is

### console log

```
111
222
```

This is because the actual module is loaded only once, is there a way to tell RequireJS to load module twice, or in other words have two separate namespaces?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why not create namespace inside lib (http://jsfiddle.net/cFEeR/1/):

```
if (typeof define !== 'function') { var define = require('amdefine')(module); }
define('lib',function () {
    var namespaces = {}
    var Namespace = function() {
        this.opt = 0
    }

    Namespace.prototype.set = function(x) { this.opt = x },
    Namespace.prototype.show = function() { console.log(this.opt) }

    return function(name) {
        if (!namespaces[name]) namespaces[name] = new Namespace()
        return namespaces[name]
    }
})

requirejs(['lib'], function(Lib) {
    var lib = Lib('test')
    var lib2 = Lib('test1')
    lib.set(111)
    lib2.set(222)
    lib.show()
    lib2.show()
});
```